# How can I say "Something which want to do but it impossible to happen" in the most formal way?

Tags: present-perfect

### Consider this situation:

You sent an application for a job, then the company boss sends you an email, and tells you if you are in town, he likes to meet you in person.

## Is it correct to say?

**"It could have been a great pleasure to meet you, but unfortunately I am currently in Russia."**

I'm not sure what tense I should use, and I'm pretty sure the above sentence is incorrect. At the same time, I want it as much as possible in a **formal and polite** way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> "It could have been a great pleasure to meet you, but unfortunately I am currently in Russia."

Why add **currently** with **am** ?

'Am' means 'currently'.

My sentence would be:

> "It would have been a great pleasure to meet you, unfortunately I am in Russia."

Again, the word 'but' appeared needless.

Comment: For me personally adding 'currently' sounds more polite.

Comment: I beg to disagree. If you want it more polite say "It would have been a great pleasure to meet your [good-self] , unfortunately I am in Russia." A man can not be at 2 places at one time, true ?

Answer (score 0):

It's not so much the tense as the word choice. Try:

> It ***w***ould have been a great pleasure to meet you, but unfortunately***,*** I am currently in Russia

I've added a comma after *unfortunately* and turned the *could* into a *would*.